# try/catch for looped SQL statements

Tags: php, loops, pdo, try-catch

I'm trying to identify the full SQL statement for a try/catch failure.   Here is the code:

```
try {
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->beginTransaction();

    for($counter=0;$counter<sizeof($sql);$counter++) {
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql[$counter]);
        $conn->exec($sql[$counter]);
    }
    $conn->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $err_message = "Failed while saving process....";
    log_event('submit_scores.php', $err_message);
    $err_message = "The following SQL statements were in the queue:";
    log_event('submit_scores.php', $err_message);
    for($counter=0;$counter<sizeof($sql);$counter++) {
        /* \t should be a tab character to indent the sql statements */
        $err_message = "\t" . $sql[$counter];
        log_event('submit_scores.php', $err_message);
    }

    $conn->rollBack();
    $message = "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    echo $message;
    $err_message = "\t" . $message;
    log_event('submit_scores.php', $err_message);
    return;
}
```

This currently logs all SQL statements to a log file (through the log_event function).   It will then generate an error (improper SQL Statement), but my issue is that the error message is generic:

```
2017-08-25 09:19:28 - submit_scores.php:    Failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax 
error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near ',210,,      ,,,     )' at line 4
```

I can see the problem, but I'd prefer to NOT log every SQL statement in the loop and simply log the FULL SQL statement that failed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is inside `$sql[$counter]`? And you're both preparing *and* executing a separate query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the exception is thrown by the `->exec()` call, you can move your `try`/`catch` into your loop and then just reference the last attempted query you called:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->beginTransaction();

for($counter=0;$counter<sizeof($sql);$counter++) {
    try {
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql[$counter]);
        $conn->exec($sql[$counter]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "This is the query ($counter) that failed: " . $sql[$counter];
        $conn->rollBack();
        return;
    }
}
$conn->commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not re-use your `$counter` variable in the `catch` block and / or loop over all your sql statements: You know the last statement that has failed as that is `$sql[$counter]` at the moment the exception is thrown.

So instead of looping over all your statements, you should only log `$sql[$counter]`.